# Large table access from c++ functions with boost::python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I'm generating a very large lookup table in C++ and using it from a variety of C++ functions. These functions are exposed to python using boost::python.

When not used as part of a class the desired behaviour is achieved. When I try and use the functions as part of a class written in just python I run in to issues accessing the lookup table.

```
    ------------------------------------
    C++ for some numerical heavy lifting
    ------------------------------------
    include <boost/python>

    short really_big_array[133784630]

    void fill_the_array(){
      //Do some things which populate the array
    }

    int use_the_array(std::string thing){
      //Lookup a few million things in the array depending on thing
      //Return some int dependent on the values found
    }

    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bigarray){
      def("use_the_array", use_the_array)
      def("fill_the_array", fill_the_array)
    }

    ---------
    PYTHON Working as desired
    ---------
    import bigarray

    if __name__ == "__main__"
        bigarray.fill_the_array()
        bigarray.use_the_array("Some Way")
        bigarray.use_the_array("Some Other way")
    #All works fine

    ---------
    PYTHON Not working as desired
    ---------
    import bigarray

    class BigArrayThingDoer():
    """Class to do stuff which uses the big array,
    use_the_array() in a few different ways
    """
    def __init__(self,other_stuff):
        bigarray.fill_the_array()
        self.other_stuff = other_stuff

    def use_one_way(thing):
        return bigarray.use_the_array(thing)

    if __name__ == "__main__"
        big_array_thing_doer = BigArrayThingDoer()
        big_array_thing_doer.use_one_way(thing)
    #Segfaults or random data
```

I think I am probably not exposing enough to python to make sure the array is accessible at the right times, but im not quite sure exactly what I shoudld be exposing. Equally likely that there is some sort of problem involving ownership of the lookup table.

I dont ever need to manipulate the lookup table except via the other c++ functions.

Comment: If the variable `really_big_array` is declared at the global scope, , then it will be accessible to *all* [translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) which have a correct declaration.

Comment: `use_one_way` doesn't take a `self` parameter. This is where you tell us `that isn't my actual code` and we wonder what exactly you expect us to base an answer on, then.

Comment: @kfsone Nearly, this where I tell you `that isn't my actual code but my actual code shared the same problem` and that I am in fact an idiot. Probably got so caught up trying to get boost working like I wanted earlier that when something else broke I got stuck thinking it was to blame. Thanks for spotting the obvious when I didnt. Thanks Joachim for at least making me worry that I had just done something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a self in a definition. Used key word arguments where I should probably have used keyword only arguments so got no error when running.